# Can't save API response to the window object

Tags: javascript

I have two pages and when use clicks continue on page1, I am calling an API and browser opens page2.
Meanwhile async process is happening and I am trying to save results of API response in the window object. After that I am trying to get access to those values on window object, which are undefined.
What am I doing wrong in my async function?

```
        const {input} = this.state;
        this.props.history.push('/step2');

        generateBook(payload)
        .then(res => {
            input.id= res.data.bookId;
            input.color= res.data.color;
            window.input = input;
        })
```

On page2 I am trying to get access to the `window.input.id` ad `window.input.color`

Comment: You could store your response data in localStorage or sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

Plese use the following way to pass data to `step2`

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/step2',
  state: {
    inputData:input
  }
})
```

you can retrive it via `this.props.location.state` in `step2` route

Comment: I know similar solution with this.props.history.push and it works and I am sure that your solution will work as well. I am just trying to understand why my initial approach didn't work?
Is it because route has been changed and I am now on different window?